# How to zero out milliseconds using new Date Time API of Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I would like to get the date & time now and from that do the following:
(i)   set the month to the first and
(ii)  zero out everything after the month
(iii) calculate the date 1 year and 1 month back and
How can I do this using the **new Date-Time API of Java**?

```
jshell> import java.time.LocalDateTime;
jshell> import java.time.ZoneId;

jshell> LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
$3 ==> 2021-01-29T01:41:14.273303

jshell> $3.minusYears(1).minusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0);
$4 ==> 2019-12-01T00:00:00.273303

jshell> $4.atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT"));
$5 ==> 2019-12-01T00:00:00.273303Z[GMT]

jshell> $5.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
$6 ==> 1575158400273
```

However, what I want is the equivalent of the below:

```
$4 ==> 2019-12-01T00:00:00.000000
```

Any ideas on how to do it? Will really appreciate the help.

Comment: Use `LocalDate` not `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: `LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay()` with all the other adjustments you want there too?

Comment: **`LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* class** to use here. If you want to track moments, points on the timeline, do *not* use that class. Use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`. This has been covered many many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more. And search thoroughly before posting.

Comment: If you want the count of milliseconds between the first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC and the first moment of a year ago from today as seen in UTC: `LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).minusYears( 1 ).atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`. See [this code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nnvW7F).

Comment: I suggest `YearMonth.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusYears(1).minusMonths(1).atDay(1).atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)`. It yields `2019-12-01T00:00Z`.